# how to get last line first 2 character of a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have  files containing below format, generated by another system

```
 12;453453;TBS;OPPS;
 12;453454;TGS;OPPS;
 12;453455;TGS;OPPS;
 12;453456;TGS;OPPS;
 20;787899;THS;CLST;
 33;786789;
```

i have to check the last line contains 33 , then have to continue to copy the file/files to other location. else discard the file.

currently I am doing as below

```
tail -1 abc.txt >> c.txt
awk '{print substr($0,0,2)}' c.txt
```

then if the o/p is saved to another variable and copying. 
**Can anyone suggest any other simple way.**

Thank you!

R/

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you have the following input file:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
e
agc
```

Then you can run the following commands (`grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `cut`) to get the first 2 char of last line:

**AWK**

```
$ awk 'END{print substr($0,0,2)}' file
ag
```

**SED**

```
$ sed -n '$s/^\(..\).*/\1/p' file                             
ag
```

**GREP**

```
$ tail -1 file | grep -oE '^..' 
ag
```

**CUT**

```
$ tail -1 file | cut -c '1-2' 
ag
```

**BASH SUBSTRING**

```
line=$(tail -1 file); echo ${line:0:2}
```

All of those commands do what you are looking for, the `awk` command will just do the operation on the last line of the file so you do not need `tail` anymore, the said command will extract the last line of the file and store it in its pattern buffer, then replace everything that is not the first 2 chars by nothing and then print the pattern buffer (the 2 fist char of the last line), another solution is just to `tail` the last line of the file and to extract the first 2 chars using `grep`, by piping those 2 commands you can also do it in one step without using intermediate variables, files.

Now if you want to put everything in one script this become:

```
$ more file check_2chars.sh 
::::::::::::::
file
::::::::::::::
a
b
c
d
e
33abc
::::::::::::::
check_2chars.sh
::::::::::::::
#!/bin/bash
s1=$(tail -1 file | cut -c 1-2) #you can use other commands from this post
s2=33

if [ "$s1" == "$s2" ] 
then
   echo "match" #implement the copy/discard logic
fi
```

**Execution:**

```
$ ./check_2chars.sh
match
```

I will let you implement the copy/discard logic

**PROOF:**

[image]

Comment: #!/bin/bash
     s1 == tail -1 abc.txt | cut -c 1-2
      s2 = 33
    if [ "$s1" == "$s2" ]
then

    echo match
  fi
--- I want like this.

Comment: @Rathi: following your comment I have added a small script as requested

Comment: Thanks Allan, but the O/P is not showing the result.
 #!/bin/bash
s1=$(tail -1 abc.txt | cut -c 1-2)
s2=33

if [ "$s1" == "$s2" ]
then
   echo match
fi

Comment: @Rathi: I tested it on my server and it is working, now are you sure there is no empty line at the end of the file? also note that spaces are important in `bash` in the `if` clause. If the script is not working then run only the command `tail -1 abc.txt | cut -c 1-2` in your shell to be sure that it returns `33`, if it is the case then your problem comes from the `if` clause. There is no space before the `33` right?

Comment: @Rathi: Could you have a look at the screenshots that I have attached as well? Thanks

Comment: What about `read -r line < <(tail -n 1 file); echo ${line:0:2}`? Good answer by the way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: nice answer as well, I will add it! But I don't think we need the whole `read -r` and `process substitution` for this: so what about: `line=$(tail -1 file); echo ${line:0:2}`

Comment: I already updated the comment. Originally I had the first two characters of the first line, then changed to using *process substitution* with tail as you mention.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Simpler: `tail -1 file | { read -N2 x ; code that uses $x goes here ; }`... but less practical.  Might be of use if `$x` isn't needed for long.

Comment: Yep, I like that too and the fact you *brace enclosed* the `read`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Allan.

Comment: @Rathi: You are welcome! If you think that my answer solved your issue, could you put it as correct answer please? also do not hesitate to vote up answers that have helped you! Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Given the task of either copying or deleting files based on their contents, shell variables aren't necessary.

Using the `sed` `F`**ile name** command and `xargs` the whole task can be done in just one line:

```
find | xargs -l sed -n '${/^33/!F}' | xargs -r rm ; cp * dest/dir/
```

Or preferably, with *GNU* `sed`:

```
sed -sn '${/^33/!F}' * | xargs -r rm ; cp * dest/dir/
```

Or if all the filenames contain no whitespace:

```
rm -r $(sed -sn '${/^33/!F}' *) ; cp * dest/dir/
```

That assumes all the files in the current directory are to be tested.

1. `sed` looks at the last line (`$`) of every file, and runs what's in the curly braces.
2. If any of those last lines line do not begin with *33* (`/^33/!`), `sed` outputs just those unwanted file names (`F`).
3. Supposing the unwanted files are named *foo* and *baz* -- those are piped to `xargs` which runs `rm foo baz`.
4. At this point the only files left should be copied over to *dest/dir/*: `cp * dest/dir/`.

It's efficient, `cp` and `rm` need only be run once.

---

If a shell variable *must* be used, here are two more methods:

Using `tail` and `bash`, store first two chars of the last line to `$n`:

```
n="$(tail -1 abc.txt)" n="${n:0:2}"
```

Here's a more portable *POSIX* shell version:

```
n="$(tail -1 abc.txt)" n="${n%${n#??}}"
```

Comment: See [Make single instance of `sed` with multiple filenames skip to next file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278122/make-single-instance-of-sed-with-multiple-filenames-skip-to-next-file/49278414#49278414) for an example of why the `-s` switch is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may explicitly test with sed for the last line ($) starting with 33 (/^33.*/):

```
echo " 12;453453;TBS;OPPS;
12;453454;TGS;OPPS;
12;453455;TGS;OPPS;
12;453456;TGS;OPPS;
20;787899;THS;CLST;
33;786789;" | sed -n "$ {/^33.*/p}"
33;786789;
```

If you store the result in a variable, you may test it for being empty or not:

```
lastline33=$(echo " 12;453453;TBS;OPPS;
12;453454;TGS;OPPS;
12;453455;TGS;OPPS;
12;453456;TGS;OPPS;
20;787899;THS;CLST;
33;786789;" | sed -n "$ {/^33.*/p}")

echo $(test -n "$lastline33" && echo not null || echo null) 
not null
```

Probably you like the regular expression to contain the semicolon, because else it would match 330, 331, ...339, 33401345 and so on, but maybe that can be excluded from the context - to me it seems a good idea:

```
lastline33=$(sed -n "$ {/^33;.*/p}" abc.txt)
```