# Make single instance of `sed` with multiple filenames skip to next file

Tags: sed

The `n`*ext* command in `sed` skips to the next line, but with multiple files there doesn't seem to be any command to skip to the next file.
Is there any workaround using only a ***single*** invocation of `sed`?

Demonstration of problem...

Make two simple 3-number data files:

```
seq 3 > three ; seq 10 1 13 > thirteen
```

Show that `sed` handles multiple files, (by finding all lines ending with *3* and printing the filenames), and is somewhat aware of them as distinct objects:

```
sed -n '/3$/{p;F}' three thirteen
```

Output:

```
3
three
13
thirteen
```

This next attempt to print *both* last lines doesn't work however, or rather it works as though both files were a single stream:

```
sed -n '$p' three thirteen
```

Output:

```
13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if your version supports the `-s` option:

```
$ seq 3 > three ; seq 10 1 13 > thirteen
$ sed -n '$p' three thirteen
13
$ sed -n '2p' three thirteen
2

$ sed -sn '$p' three thirteen
3
13
$ sed -sn '2p' three thirteen
2
11
```

From `man sed`:

> -s, --separate
>
> consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream.

When using the `-i` option, *GNU* `sed` uses `-s` by default.

In case the `-s` option is not available, here's an alternative with `perl`:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if eof' three thirteen
3
13
```