# With sed -s, how can I skip ahead to the next file?

Tags: sed

When using [GNU sed with the `-s`/`--separate` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#index-Working-on-separate-files), how can I skip ahead, or “fast-forward” to the end of a file or the beginning of the next? Critically, I want to do this *without* checking the rest of the lines against the whole script, so not just `1!d`.

```
s/foo/bar/      # work on some lines early in the file
[fast-forward]  # ignore the rest of this file—
                #  *do not* run the rest of the script on it
$d              # when we get to the end of this file,
                #  start the script over for the next file
```

With `-s`/`--separate`, addresses `1` & `$` refer to the first and last lines of *each file*, but there are no addresses or commands specific to files themselves (except `F` which doesn't help here except in debugging).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49278122/1144854) sounds similar, but only goes as far as discovering the `-s` option. (Thanks to that Q & A for showing me how to use it!)

Comment: I'm not at all sure my solution is best and I'd be happy for some more options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Short answer

`:ff; $!{n;b ff}`

##### Explanation

```
# Eat lines until we find the end of this file:
:ffwd       # label this spot in the script
$!{         # if not at the last line ($) of *this file*
    n       # get the next line
    b ffwd  # jump (“branch”) back up to the label
}
            # we only get here if we're at the last line of *a file*
d           # start over at the top of the script with the next line
            # (not necessary at the end of the script)
```

##### Examples

Here's an example one-liner to print only the first line containing `foo` in each file:

```bash
sed -sne '/foo/{p; b ff}; d; :ff; $!{n; b ff};' *.cfg
```

Here's a similar invocation replacing `foo` with `bar`:

```bash
sed -sne 's/foo/bar/p; t ff; d; :ff; $!{n; b ff};' *.cfg
```

Here's a longer example (for use with `sed -Esf`). It uses a similar pattern to find information that I know will be in a certain order (in a Cisco IOS config file). After the last line I care about, it formats and prints the info for that file, then fast-forwards to the end of the file.

```
#n  # don't print by default (force -n)

# Eat lines until we find hostname
:hostname
/^hostname /!{n; b hostname}
s/^hostname (\S+)/\1/  # replace pattern with just hostname value
h  # (over)write to hold space

# Eat lines until we find Loopback0
:lo0
/^interface Loopback0/!{n; b lo0}
n  # grab the next line instead (should be IP)
s/^ ip address ([.[:digit:]]+) (255\.){3}255/\1/  # replace pattern with just IP
H  # append to hold space

# Deal with what we found
g  # get hold space contents
s/\`\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*\'/\1,\2,/  # combine lines in one comma-separated line
p  # print pattern space

# Eat lines until we find the end of this file
:ffwd
$!{n; b ffwd}
# Now the script will start over with the next line,
# to wit: line 1 of the next file
```

Comment: I'd be happy for better options, either for the question as written, or any better structure for my long example, which is close to my actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -s 's/foo/bar;1{:a;n;$!ba}' file
```

At the end of the sed commands you want executed, place the snippet `n{:a;n;$!ba}` or `/regex/{:a;n;$ba}` where `n` is a line number address and `regex` is a regular expression.

This effectively loops till the end of the file when used in conjunction with `-s` option (or `-i` option).

Comment: I suppose `:label; n; $!b label` is effectively the same as `:label; $!{n; b label}`, except if it happens to be triggered when you're on the last line of the file.

Comment: @Jacktose yes, however the above solution allows the user to enforce their own "end-of-file" condition.

Comment: Can you explain? It's the same `$!` in both cases.

Comment: @Jacktose the snippet `:a;n;$!ba` is surrounded by `{`,`}`'s and is only enacted when the address (either numeric or regex) to the left of the `{ ` is matched. Thus in the solution above this is on the first line but could be on line 42 or if the word `grail` is matched.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about how to enter the fast-forwarding loop. The loop mechanism and end condition is effectively the same.